# Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0 while mine is 2.4.0 using rbenv (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails newbie here , I am trying to test an opensource project that I downloaded but when I use bundle install I get the following error , which says that my ruby is 2.3 while in gemfile it is 2.4 (although I updated ruby & I have 2.4.0 using rbenv as shown below)

I have looked this up and tried multiple solution but couldn't solve it.
I looked in the workspace for `gem 'Ruby'` but I didn't find it

Please advise.
Thanks for your help.

```
usr@ubuntu:~/Downloads/instructure-canvas-lms-cea9158$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
usr@ubuntu:~/Downloads/instructure-canvas-lms-cea9158$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0
usr@ubuntu:~/Downloads/instructure-canvas-lms-cea9158$ rbenv local
2.4.0
```

====
This question is not duplicate of the other one referenced , I tried `gem install bundler` ***before posting the question*** *and it didn't solve the issue , only when I used `rbenv -rehash` it was solved*

Comment: show the content of Gemfile and the output of command `ls -la` from the project directory.

Comment: The gemfile is segregated to multiple files , however the issue turned out to be that after `gem install bundler` , I had to do `rbenv rehash`

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @Зелёный This question is not duplicate of the other one referenced , I tried `gem install bundler` before posting the question and it didn't solve the issue , only when I used `rbenv -rehash` it was solved , the Q & A referenced are not the same as this one

Comment: @Зелёный Please remove the duplicate flag as this question is **not answered** in the question referenced , they look similar but the answer is not the same. (Please search for `rehash` in both to check what I mean)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for the future reference for other developers:

2 commands solved the issue 
`gem install bundler`
**but only when I used** 
`rbenv rehash`
things worked